# Excel using selenium webdriver

Tags: excel, selenium

Does anyone knows if i can click on the excel using selenium webdriver. 
I am able to update the excel cells,however updation in cell should update the value in corresponding cells/fields which is not happening.Its like manually i can enter the value in excel andjust click twice so the other value gets updated.So,can this clicking on any cell can be done using webdriver or any other way.Please suggest some solution..

Comment: What you mean `click on the Excel`? Do you mean to handle a table embedded in `HTML`? Provide your code + page source for table

Comment: I just want to click on any cell..That with refresh the excel and update the field

Answer (score 0):

Using WebDriver isn't for automating Desktop apps but for automating browsers. So Selelnium isn't for this purpose and it can't be done.

However, your options are:

1. Use [Google Docs's excel](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/) and then you can manipulate the data sheet with `WebDriver`.
2. Automate Excel with [UIAutomation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx) if your using C#.
3. Automate with `Robot` [class in Java](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/21-java-awt/1758-how-to-use-robot-class-in-java.html).
4. You can do it with AutoIt integrated in your script, but it will require coordinates since the cells in Excel don't have ID's, and it can be run via exe files or you can use [autoitx4java](https://github.com/accessrichard/autoitx4java).

Another option is to access the data directly with some framework that manipulates excel, like [Apache's POI HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) etc... depending on your programming language.

Comment: Yes I am using Apache poi for the same.But I want to click twice on any cell so that it can update the value.I s robot class can be used for excel here??

Comment: You didn't mention your programming language.. I guess it's Java... Robot can be used but not recommended since it will be by coordinates.

Comment: Yes its Java..Robot can only be used in case of web I guess.I am.not sure how you use it here.Also is there any way in Apache where I can just click in excel cell.Its like a excel parser wherein we need to give values and other values will be updated based on our values and formulas.The values are not getting updated for me.

Comment: Robot is for Desktop rather than for web, you have a snippet in the link. Apache's POI isn't for clicking a cell

Comment: ok. So how it can be done.Can i try Auto IT for clicking and integrate it with my selenium script?

Comment: Robot is not moving the mouse in excel,instead its moving the mouse in my current window only.How to make robot class to move mouse or cursor in excel sheet?

Comment: I think your not using Robot correctly... AutoIt can be integrated, see update.

Comment: Can u tell how to use robot in case of excel.I am.not able to understand why it's not going to excel.Its just clicking on the same window in which I have written the program.How to move it to excel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128724/discussion-between-moshisho-and-dheeraj-kateja).

Comment: If i am keeping the excel open,its giving me java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Comment: That exception isn't telling me a lot since I don't have access to your code.. Anyway, I've put lots of effort into your question and gained nothing, so your on your own mate.. ;)

Comment: That exception means file is not being identified.Yes I appreciate that and thank u for all the help.But robot class in not able to click on the excel.I just want a way to click on excel

Comment: AutoIt can do it: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ it has good documentation and examples.

Comment: Ok...I will try it.Thank you for your valuable time for this issue.Thanks a ton mate!!!

Comment: Juts for your info..Robot works only for browser automation.No offence,but robot cant be used with excel hence its not moving to excel window.Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No problem, hope you'll solve it. Robot is better for desktop apps than browsers, see here: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/21-java-awt/1758-how-to-use-robot-class-in-java.html